# Spring Web App - CannotLoadBeanClassException Cannot find class [package] for bean with name 'somename'

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I would be grateful if someone can figure out my problem. I searched and found a lot of similar questions. But not able to find a solution to it. I apologize for asking the same question. But I am struggling and frustrated with this problem.

I have a web-app with many projects deployed on eclipse. I am using spring framework. Everything was working fine . I cleaned all projects in eclipse and i started the server. And my browser is throwing this error. I tried to restart  server and all possible fixes but nothing worked.

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class[org.company.ain.authenticate.AuthenticateUser] for bean with name 'authenticate'
```

This is my .xml file

```
<bean name="authenticate" class="org.company.ain.authenticate.AuthenticateUser">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

I want to know two things.

- Whether eclipse erases my classpath once i clean all projects?
- What is the solution to my above problem.

Comment: Try re-deploying, if it solves the problem. And also check that org.company.ain.authenticate.AuthenticateUser is actually there.

Comment: Tried both. yes it is there. Doesnt work. It throws same error.

Comment: Well than you'll have to post the code which is causing the problem.

Comment: It is not problem with code. My code was working fine these days. Just that I cleaned all the projects on eclipse. So its throwing this error.

Comment: Cleaning does not cause problems, surely there is something wrong either in your setup or with your code.

Answer (score 0):

My working example is for multiple hibernate, I wish it will be usefull for you.

Data source

```
 <!-- DATA SOURCE -->
    <bean id="_dataSourceProxy"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
       <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
       <property name="jndiName" value="${connection.jndiName}"></property>
       <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"></property>
       <property name="cache" value="false"></property>
       <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"></property>
    </bean>
```

Hibernate

```
 <!-- HIBERNATE -->
 <bean id="_hibernateSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="_dataSourceProxy"></ref>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">false</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
            <prop key="connection.useUnicode">true</prop>   
            <prop key="connection.characterEncoding">utf-8</prop>


            <prop key="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>hibernate/content/Content.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/content/ContentMeta.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Hibernate Conf for multi

```
 <!-- Content Repo -->
    <bean id="_contentRepository"
        class="XXXX">
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
        <property name="_senderEmail" value="${smtp.senderEmail}"></property>    
        <property name="_hibernateSessionFactory">
            <ref bean="_hibernateSessionFactory"></ref>
        </property>
        <property name="_authService">
            <ref bean="_authService"></ref>
        </property>   
        <property name="_languageRepository">
            <ref bean="_languageRepository"></ref>
        </property>  
        <property name="_locationRepository">
            <ref bean="_locationRepository"></ref>
        </property>          
        <property name="_velocityEngine">
            <ref bean="_velocityEngine"></ref>
        </property>
        <property name="_mailSender">
            <ref bean="_mailSender"></ref>
        </property>                                                   
    </bean>
```

Example repo:

```
<!-- Location Repo -->
    <bean id="_locationRepository"
        class="XXXX">
        <property name="_hibernateSessionFactory">
            <ref bean="_hibernateSessionFactory"></ref>
        </property>
    </bean>
```